# 22.04, How to change default webcam?

Tags: 20.04, webcam

I am brand new to Ubuntu and just need to figure out how to change my  default webcam from my built in webcam to a USB camera. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no "default webcam". When more than one is available each one can be selected but it's a per app setting, not system wide.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's machine-specific, but I ended up interrupting the boot (f12 in my case) and scrolling around until I found the option to 'disable camera' tucked under misc devices. not very elegant, but now I'm looking at the 3d printer and not my ugly mug.